# What are these icons on an Android?

Tags: applications

Could someone please tell what these apps are?

[image: photo of screen phone]

Comment: Device is a Samsung s8 edge. Not sure about operating system.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Icon on the **left** is the notification by the app **Musical.ly**.

- musical.ly is a global video community with editing tools and share video with the world.

[image]

Icon on the **right** is the notification by the app **Smart Manager** in Samsung.

- This app is used to manage battery, storage, RAM, Device Security etc